# Creating a PDF with Content Hidden Depending on a Response to a Form

Tags: pdf, conditionals

Would it possible to create a say 3-page PDF document with LaTeX such that

1. On page 1 the reader is presented with a yes/no question through something like a radio button;
2. If the answer is yes, then the reader may go on to page 2 and 3;
3. If the answer is no, then the reader goes to page 3, while page 2 remains hidden to him/her.

The idea is to create document with a non-disclosure clause in the cover page. If accepted, green light with reading the whole document. If declined, the access is only granted from one other page onwards, or to none.

A tricky implication is that page 2 in the example should ideally remain inaccessible also to previews, thumbnails and so forth.

I am aware of a similar unanswered question ['conditional text triggered by form'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227349/conditional-text-triggered-by-form). If my question is too far-fetched, as I fear, it would be interesting to address that question instead.

Thanks for dealing with this.

Answer (score 1):

The only means I can think of is OCGs (PDF Layers). However, it cannot eliminate pages, only hide their content.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ocgx2} % supports multi-page PDF Layers
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
I agree \raisebox{-0.25\height}{\huge%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\showocg{classified}{\color{red}$\circ$}}%
  \begin{ocg}{I agree.}{classified}{off}$\color{green}\bullet$\end{ocg}%
} to tell nothing about the following content to anybody.

Or \hyperlink{public}{skip} the classified content.

\newpage
\begin{ocg}[printocg=never,exportocg=never]{...}{classified}{off}
\kant[1-20]
\end{ocg}
\newpage

\hypertarget{public}{}The following information is public:

\Huge The End.

\end{document}
```